# How to to Print a div with Horizontal scroll bars

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage with vertical and horizontal scroll bars. `window.print()` is printing only the visible content in the window.

How to print the scroll  content in the window?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post EFFORT and CODE.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, in your stylesheet need media-query

```
@media print {
  .class-of.you-element {
    overflow: visible
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a CSS default registereded bottom scroll bar.

`overflow-x: scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

All above answers will work but you may want to add a specific width/max-width and then use the `overflow-x:scroll`